# Nested conditionals with Switchee?

Tags: switchee, nesting

I'm trying to use Switchee for this scenario:

```
{if variable_1}

    {if variable_2} some text {if:else} some other text {/if}

{if:else}
nothing to show!
{/if}
```

So, if i want to use Switchee i need to nest two plugins?

```
{exp:switchee variable="{variable_1}" parse="inward"}

    {case value="{variable_1}"}

        {exp:switchee2 variable="{variable_2}" parse="inward"}
            {case2 value="{variable_2}"}  some text {/case2}
            {case2 default="yes"} some other text {/case2}
        {/exp:switchee2}

    {/case}

    {case default="yes"}
     nothing to show
    {/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

Help please! :)
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nested instances of switchee **should not** have the `exp` prefix.

```
{exp:switchee variable="{variable_1}" parse="inward"}

    {case value="{variable_1}"}

        {switchee variable="{variable_2}" parse="inward"}
            {case value="{variable_2}"}  some text {/case}
            {case default="yes"} some other text {/case}
        {/switchee}

    {/case}

    {case default="yes"}
     nothing to show
    {/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

Or you can test both variables at once:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{variable_1}/{variable_2}" parse="inward"}

    {case value="{variable_1}/{variable_2}"}
        some text
    {/case}

    {case value="{variable_1}/"}
        some other text
    {/case}

    {case}

    {case value="/"}
        nothing to show
    {/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

---

You should know that `variable_1` and `variable_2` need to be parsed before switchee or this code **will not** work.

Comment: note: you can use switchee inside a channel_entries tag on variables. So, var_1 and var_2 need only be early parsed if you use switchee outside of any other tags.